# R: Inverse fft() to confirm my manual DFT algorithm inaccurate?

Tags: r, fft, dft

Using R, before assessing some metric of accuracy on my own manual implementation of DFT, I wanted to do a sanity check on how well stats::fft() performs by doing the following:

```
sig.ts = ts( sin(2*pi*freq1*t) + sin(2*pi*freq2*t) );
sig.rt = fft(fft(sig.ts)/N, inverse="true");
#the two plots so perfectly align that you can't see them both
max(abs(sig.ts - sig.rt)) / max(sig.ts);
#arbitrary crude accuracy metric=1.230e-15 - EXCELLENT!
```

But I wanted to write the code for DFT myself, to ensure I understand it, then invert it in the hopes that it would be the same:

```
##The following is the slow DFT for now, not the FFT...
sR = 102.4;  #the number of Hz at which we sample
freq1=3; freq2=12;  #frequency(ies) of the wave
t = seq(1/sR,10, 1/sR);
sig.ts = ts( sin(2*pi*freq1*t) + sin(2*pi*freq2*t) );
N=length(t);  kk=seq(0,N/2-1, 1);  nn=seq(0,N-1, 1);
for(k in kk){ 
  sig.freqd[k]=0;
  for(n in nn){
    sig.freqd[k] = sig.freqd[k] + sig.ts[n+1]*exp(-j*2*pi*n*k/N);  } }
sig.freqd = (1/N)*sig.freqd; #for Normalization

#Checking the "accuracy" of my manual implementation of DFT...
sig.freqd_inv=Re(fft(sig.freqd, inverse="true"));
plot(t[1:100], window(sig.ts,end=100), col="black",  type="l",lty=1,lwd=1, xaxt="n");  
lines(t[1:100],window(sig.freqd_inv,end=100), col="red",   type="l",lty=1,lwd=1, xaxt="n");
   axis(1, at=seq(round(t[1],1),round(t[length(t)],1), by=0.1), las=2);
max(abs(sig.ts[1:(N/2-1)] - sig.freqd_inv)) / max(sig.ts[1:(N/2-1)]);  #the metric here =1.482 unfortunately
```

Even without the metric, the plot makes it obvious that something's off here - it's lower amplitude, maybe out of phase, and more jagged. In all of my self-studying, I will say that I am a bit confused about how sensitive this all is to vector length..as well as how to ensure that the imaginary component's phase information is taken into account when plotting.

Bottom line, any insight into what's wrong with my DFT algorithm would be helpful. I don't want to just blackbox my use of functions - I want to understand these things more deeply before moving on to more complicated functions.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: @SleuthEye thanks but leaving that scaling out makes it far worse. With it, the plot mostly appears to be out of phase.

Answer (score 0):

The main issues arise from the signal indexing. First to get a full transform usable by R's `fft(..., inverse = TRUE)`, you would need to compute all `N` coefficients (even if the coefficients above `N/2-1` could be obtained by symmetry).
Then you should realize that array indexing in R are 1-based. So, while indexing `sig.freqd[k]`, the index `k` should start at 1 instead of 0. Since the argument to `exp(-1i*2*pi*n*k/N) should start with` n=0`and`k=0`, you'll need to adjust the indices:

```
kk=seq(1,N, 1);  nn=seq(1,N, 1);
for(k in kk){ 
  sig.freqd[k]=0i;
  for(n in nn){
    sig.freqd[k] = sig.freqd[k] + sig.ts[n]*exp(-1i*2*pi*(n-1)*(k-1)/N);
  }
}
```

I've also changed you usage of `j` to represent the imaginary number `1i` since that's the usual notation recognized by R (and R was complaining about it when trying your posted sample as-is). If you had defined `j=1i` that shouldn't affect the results.

Note also that R's [`fft`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/fft) is unnormalized. So to obtain the same result for the forward transform, your DFT implementation should not include the `1/N` normalization. On the other hand, you will need to add this factor as a final step in order to get the full-circle forward+backward transform to match the original signal.

With these changes you should have the following code:

```
##The following is the slow DFT for now, not the FFT...
sR = 102.4;  #the number of Hz at which we sample
freq1=3; freq2=12;  #frequency(ies) of the wave
t = seq(1/sR,10, 1/sR);
sig.ts = ts( sin(2*pi*freq1*t) + sin(2*pi*freq2*t) );
N=length(t);  kk=seq(1,N, 1);  nn=seq(1,N, 1);
for(k in kk){ 
  sig.freqd[k]=0i;
  for(n in nn){
    sig.freqd[k] = sig.freqd[k] + sig.ts[n]*exp(-1i*2*pi*(n-1)*(k-1)/N);
  }
}

#Checking the "accuracy" of my manual implementation of DFT...
sig.freqd_inv=(1/N)*Re(fft(sig.freqd, inverse="true"));
plot(t[1:100], window(sig.ts,end=100), col="black",  type="l",lty=1,lwd=2,    xaxt="n");  
lines(t[1:100],window(sig.freqd_inv,end=100), col="red",   type="l",lty=2,lwd=1, xaxt="n");
axis(1, at=seq(round(t[1],1),round(t[length(t)],1), by=0.1), las=2);
max(abs(sig.ts - sig.freqd_inv)) / max(sig.ts)
```

This should yield a metric around `1.814886e-13`, which is probably more in line with what you were expecting. The corresponding plot should also be showing the orignal signal and the roundtrip signal overlapping:

[image: Plot of original signal (black), and overlapped roundtrip signal (dashed red)]